# How can a function handle a NumPy array input, which is not comma-separated?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I wrote a function to modify a 2D NumPy array:

```
def fun(state,r,c):
    state = np.array(state)
    state[r][c] = 0
    return state
```

To test it, I used this format:

```
state = np.array([[1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1],[0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1]])
```

However this function should also handle input, where the array is not comma separated:

```
state=
[[1 1 1 1 1]
 [1 0 0 0 1]
 [0 0 0 1 1]
 [1 1 1 1 1]
 [1 1 1 1 1]]
```

How can this function handle the NumPy array input, which is not comma-separated?
Whatever I tried so far to fix it, a SyntaxError was raised.

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Your array with no comma is not valid python. Whatever you do to the function won’t fix that it’s input is not valid.

Comment: It's about method `__repr__` and `__str__`. You don't need to care about them at first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be careful to distinguish things like `list`, `array` and strings - their displays.

Here's your syntax error:

```
In [412]: state=
     ...: [[1 1 1 1 1]
     ...:  [1 0 0 0 1]
     ...:  [0 0 0 1 1]
     ...:  [1 1 1 1 1]
     ...:  [1 1 1 1 1]]
  File "<ipython-input-412-1d0565808329>", line 1
    state=
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

That is not valid python.  But it does look like the print display of an array, a string.

You can make a multiline string:

```
In [413]: state="""
     ...: [[1 1 1 1 1]
     ...:  [1 0 0 0 1]
     ...:  [0 0 0 1 1]
     ...:  [1 1 1 1 1]
     ...:  [1 1 1 1 1]]"""
In [414]: state
Out[414]: '\n[[1 1 1 1 1]\n [1 0 0 0 1]\n [0 0 0 1 1]\n [1 1 1 1 1]\n [1 1 1 1 1]]'
In [415]: type(state)
Out[415]: str
```

Your first case starts with a list:

```
In [417]: state = [[1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1],[0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1]]
In [418]: state
Out[418]: [[1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1], [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1]]
In [419]: type(state)
Out[419]: list
```

an array made from the list:

```
In [420]: arr = np.array(state)
In [421]: arr
Out[421]: 
array([[1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1]])
```

The print display of the array:

```
In [422]: print(arr)
[[1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1]
 [0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1]]
```

That print display is not intended for parsing, recreating an array. While it's not impossible, I think a beginner should not go there.  There are more important things to learn.